# bower.json doesn't show in Visual Studio 2015 solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I read everywhere that VS2015 shows all files in the directory. However, I don't see `bower.json` unless I click "show all files" icon. Since there is no option "include in/exclude from project" as there was before, I don't understand how this is controlled. Other service files (`package.json`, `project.json`, etc. ) **do** show up, but not `bower.json`.

How do I include `bower.json` in solution explorer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right Click on the `bower.json` file then show this in Solution Explorer. That's it

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also noticed that the files that do not show in Solution Explorer are listed in .xproj file

Answer (score 1):

[image: button to click]

First click the 3rd button from left at the top of solution explorer menu to show all files.
Then right click on the bower.json file and select "Show in Solution Explorer". (If you prefer, do the same with .bowerrc)
Finally click the 3rd button from left at the top of solution explorer menu again to hide all files while bower.json keeps visible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the question carefully before responding! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try 'bower init' under your project folder. You might need to install node.js/npm and bower first.